# Composite manipulated images with RMagick

Tags: ruby, image, imagemagick, image-manipulation, rmagick

I'm trying to create a composite image from two original images, a background and an overlay which I manipulate using RMagick like follows:

```
background = ImageList.new("foo.png")
overlay_original = ImageList.new("bar.png")
overlay_resized = overlay_original.resize_to_fit(400,400)
overlay_cropped = overlay_resized.crop(NorthWestGravity, 400, 200)

new_image = ImageList.new
new_image = new_image.composite_layers(background)
new_image = new_image.composite_layers(overlay_cropped)
```

When I do this it gives me the following error: `ArgumentError: no images in this image list`

When I just try to check the length of the `background` and `overlay_cropped` image lists (`background.length` and `overlay_cropped.length`) it tells me the  `background` image list has 1 image, but that `overlay_cropped` has no images:

`NoMethodError: undefined method length' for bar.png PNG 640x1096=>400x200 400x400+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit:Magick::Image`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I"m guessing the answer is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by changing it to the following:

```
marketing_image = marketing_image.composite(background, NorthWestGravity, 0, 0, OverCompositeOp)
marketing_image = marketing_image.composite(overlay_cropped, NorthWestGravity, 327, 126, OverCompositeOp)
```